# How to get filename of uploaded Safecracker File image?

Tags: file-uploads, zoo-visitor, safecracker-file, uploads, filename

I'm using Zoo Visitor which advocates the **Safecracker File** field type for user uploaded avatars.

Safecracker File stores the image reference as `{filedir_x}filename`.

I'm wanting to use EE's image manipulation to **crop and resize** the uploaded image so I need to be able to output src attributes of the form…

```
/path/to/images/avatars/uploads/_subfolder/filename
```

How can I get hold of the **filename** in my tag output? Do I have to resort to custom PHP or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, OK…

> "SafeCracker File inherits the tags of the standard File field"

…so I can just use the appropriate [single variable](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/custom_fields.html#single-variable-usage) parameter such as…

```
{member_avatar:image_manipulation_short_name}
```

Must read more carefully before posting!